# groovy parse local html file

Tags: groovy

I am working on a groovy script that will get all the local html files and parse certain tags in them. I tried using something like html clean and it just is not working. I tried to read each line but that only works when the stuff I need is on 1 line. I have this script up on github, https://github.com/jrock2004/johns-octopress-scripts/blob/master/convertCompiledPosts/convertPosts.groovy. Thanks for any input

Edit: So I am getting closer. I have this code now

```
def parser = new org.cyberneko.html.parsers.SAXParser()
new XmlParser( parser ).parse( curFile+ "/index.html" ).with { page ->
    page.'**'.DIV.grep { it.'@class'?.contains 'entry-content' }.each {
    println it
    println "--------------------------------"
    }
}
```

And what it prints is

```
DIV[attributes={class=entry-content}; value=[P[attributes={}; value=[As an automation developer, I have learned how to write code in Java. When I am having an issue, one of the nice things that you can do is debug your code, line by line. For the longest I had wished that something like this existed in PHP. I have come to find out that you can actually debug code, like I do in Java. This is such a helpful task because I do not have to waste time using var_dump and such on variables or results. In your apache/php server you need to install and or enable something called, A[attributes={href=http://xdebug.org/}; value=[Xdebug]], . I will work on a tutorial on how to use xdebug while writing code in Sublime Text 2. So keep an eye out on my blog and or, A[attributes={href=http://www.youtube.com/jrock20041}; value=[YouTube]], channel for this tutorial.]]]]
```

So basically what I want is I wall the text including the html elements in the div with the class entry-content. If you want to see the page it can be found here -- http://jcwebconcepts.net/blog/2013/02/02/xdebug/

Thanks for your help

Comment: Try nekohtml: https://gist.github.com/lyhcode/4387321

Comment: Does not appear to work. Not getting error or anything

Comment: Do you have a simple failing example?

Comment: Tim, its not failing. When I run the file with the code I added above I get a bunch of blank lines. I think the problem is that inside the div it is all nested html code. So when I println it.text() its empty cause there is now text in the div

Comment: Ahhh... What did you want out?  The plain text with no html?  Or the html inside the div?

Comment: I want all the html in the div. I think I may need to alter the neko settings

Comment: Updated my answer.  That should print the html including the div itself -- as obviously there could be free text inside the div as well as a `<p>` element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does work...  Save the HTML for this page to a file, then you can parse it.

The following code prints the name of the author of every comment on the page:

```
@Grab('net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:1.9.16')
def parser = new org.cyberneko.html.parsers.SAXParser()

new XmlParser( parser ).parse( file ).with { page ->
  page.'**'.A.grep { it.'@class'?.contains 'comment-user' }.each {
    println it.text()
  }
}
```

When `file` is set to be a `File` pointing to the saved HTML (or a `String` containing the URL of this question), it prints:

```
tim_yates
jrock2004
tim_yates
```

### Edit:

To print the contents of a given node, you could do (using the example from your edited question):

```
@Grab('net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:1.9.16')
import groovy.xml.*

def parser = new org.cyberneko.html.parsers.SAXParser()

new XmlParser( parser ).parse( 'http://jcwebconcepts.net/blog/2013/02/02/xdebug/' ).with { page ->
  page.'**'.DIV.grep { it.'@class'?.contains 'entry-content' }.each { it ->
    println XmlUtil.serialize( it )
  }
}
```

Comment: I think my problem was how I was looking for elements. Thanks for your help. This solved my problem.