# Where to find Groovy documentation on "queries"?

Tags: groovy

I am trying to learn more about groovy.  Specifically my use case is to read an html document and parse out info and maybe add some data to the html.  I found this post on a similar subject: [groovy parse local html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959650/groovy-parse-local-html-file?newreg=7f6834bd2e004b9eb72cfde71a421b1f) but I don't understand some of the syntax and functions used.

For example, in [this response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZr4p.png) I don't really understand what the ".with" does and the ".'**'".

So I'm hoping someone can point me to some documentation or additional info on these kind of expressions and functions.  I generally understand this use case but I want to have a better understanding so I can adapt it to my needs.

Thanks for any help or guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`with` is described here in the documentation https://groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html#_using_code_with_code_and_code_tap_code_for_repeated_operations_on_the_same_bean

And `**` is described here in the documentation (it means depth first traversal): https://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_flexible_navigation_with_children_depthfirst_and_breadthfirst

Comment: Thank Tim, that doc page on the XmlParser call will be helpful.